# Symfony2 user switch missing ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN after switch

Tags: php, symfony

When I switch as admin to a user `site.loc/?_switch_user=user@email.com` I don't get the role `ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN`.
I'm not sure which code I should show you..

Symfony Version: symfony2 2.2.2

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @see \Serializable::serialize()
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->email
    ));
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->email
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

public function isAccountNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isAccountNonLocked()
{
    return true;
}

public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return
        md5($user->getUsername()) == md5($this->getUsername()) &&
        md5(serialize($user->getGroups())) == md5(serialize($this->getGroups()));
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the other roles correctly when you switch?  Are you using a custom security listener?

Comment: The other roles are correctly, I have no security listeners. I do have a `AuthenticationHandler` on `success` that sets the login time of a user.

Comment: The only thing I can see that is different here is your serialize and unserialize function.  My class serializes $id and not $email.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement [`EquatableInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) for `User` class:

```
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable {

    // ...

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
        return $this->username === $user->getUsername();
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list($this->id, $this->username) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    // ...
}
```